I am sorry, but the quality of the developer survey went down a lot
Something happened, the questionnare quality is going down. What I would suggest, next time let it fill out by a little sample of developers and fix the questions by their comments.

"What online resources do you use to learn to code?"

Most of us do not learn to code. We can code. We learn things to solve coding problems. We have learnt to code before the start of our IT career.
If the question asks for that, how do we find and learn, the answer is this: mostly google, leading most often to Stack Overflow, official documentation or source code. The selectable choices are not even similar. At this point, I got a very strong impression that this survey was not written by a developer, more clearly not even by someone who knows developers.

"What is the source of the technical documentation you use most often to learn to code?  Select all that apply."

Ok, what is a "First-party knowledge base"? That you ask someone? This is how you formulate that you ask someone?

"When buying a new tool or software, how do you discover and research available solutions? Select all that apply."

I do not buy software without some strong external pressure and in this case, the nature of this pressure decides, what to do. This is not in the options. There is not even similar in the options.

"When asked to provide a recommendation for solving a problem at work with a new tool or software, what has been your most recent choice of the following?"

This question I do not understand. If someone asks for a recommendation for a tool or software, I always say them the solution which serves the best of their interests, in my opinion. This is not in the options, the options are various cloudy crap. I think you tried to get an answer to a different question what you have actually asked.
At this point, I stopped to fill out the survey.

"You can keep the silver badge, thanks." - the badge doesn't exist anymore anyway

@Zoe That is sad, I think some reward for filling out such a long questionnaire was useful.

These problems have existed in the survey for a number of years now. Very few of the questions seem to align with the chart they'll be presenting later.

@KevinB And like half the questions are just marketing questions in disguise

@KevinB I filled the survey maybe a ten times, but only now I experienced this. I think, something has happened, some really bad.

I think your criticism of "What online resources do you use to learn to code?" might land better if you included the choices for that question and those for the previous "How do you learn to code?" question. I am not certain if it means something closer to "How did you learn to code?" (with phrasing that would include in-progress learning for those learning to code), "how do you learn new programming languages, paradigms, frameworks, or technologies?", "how do you find answers to questions?", or some combination of these.

(continued from previous) I think the intended meaning is probably a combination of the last two (and the first, but only for people currently learning to code), but it's not completely clear.

Use Chat GPT to answer the survey. It is the only truly fitting option.

Honestly, what did you expect?

@DanMašek My remembers about the previous surveys were better and I filled them out, because I felt, the results will be somewhere heard.

(compellation - "archaic, rare ... archaic, rare ... obsolete". Perhaps rephrase?)

@PeterMortensen Wow. Thanks. Fixed (maybe).

Quality from what perspective though? As far as I know the main purpose of the survey was for the company to learn what ads to prioritize. The fact that you can glean some other things from it as well was a happy side effect.

@Gimby Yes, but an important factor in that are we. Because we need to feel ourself well on the site network. This is why do I believe, yes it has a chance that important ears will hear what we answer there. This is why I always filled out the form on my best. This year... this time, I did this.

Only ears, no important ears. What I personally get out of it is that some Youtubers I respect look at the results and vent their savage opinion on it. That's about it really. Other than that it is just a means to pass some time and think about how your own work life is going.

@Gimby Huhh I don't get that, afaik youtube has many videos quite critical to the SE (mostly because it is evil). Wow, I see really a lot of guys are talking about the dev survey. It looks none of them had the spine to get in touch with the SEDE until now...


Most of us do not learn to code. We can code. We learn things to solve
coding problems. We have learnt to code before the start of our IT
career.

We do not simply learn to code once and then we're done. My first language was C++. Then, I learned Java and the Java ecosystem. Later on, I learned Ruby. And then Python. We're continually learning things about coding - languages, frameworks, tools. If you're a professional, you're also learning about other things, such as your domain or industry or non-coding topics like requirements engineering, architectural patterns, and communication skills.
To me, this question is pretty clear. When you're learning about coding, what online resources do you use?
A search engine, like Google, is not a resource. It's a tool for finding resources. Stack Overflow questions are a resource. Someone's YouTube channel is a resource. If you use Google to find web resources, do you favor particular resource(s) over others based on their category? If so, consider that when answering this question.

Ok, what is a "First-party knowledge base"? That you ask someone? This
is how you formulate that you ask someone?

First-party is a well-defined concept. It's the information provided directly by the creator of the language, framework, or tool you're using. If you're building a Chrome extension, then the Chrome for Developers documentation and tutorials on extensions is the first-party knowledgebase. If you're working in Java, then the Oracle docs are the first-party knowledgebase.
Unfortunately, I didn't get the questions about buying or recommending tools. Not sure why, because this is something that I do as part of my job. So without seeing those details, I really can't say. But it does seem like you misunderstood the intention of at least two of the questions, so it could be misunderstanding the intent of these ones as well.


You clearly did not understand the point. My critics was not the incomprehensibility but the VLQ formulation. 2) That is "official docs". Of course you can call it "first party knowledge base", you can even call it 66 69 72 73 74 2d 70 61 72 74 79 20 6b 6e 6f 77 6c 65 64 67 65 20 62 61 73 65. Looks we have a disagreement how far is it okay to go in the corporate buzzword bingo. I would suggest to not go so far with the people you are asking things from.


Your formulation of the question is much clearer as to its intended meaning.

"A search engine, like Google, is not a resource. It's a tool for finding resources." While this is a completely reasonable position to take, the survey is not consistent on this point, as it describes a "Traditional public search engine" (as well as AI-powered search tools) as a "source of...technical documentation".

@peterh I did not get any hint of "VLQ formulation" in the questions. Although, as Ryan M points out, there is some inconsistencies regarding if a search engine is or is not a source of documentation.

Programming languages are rather trivial too on the whole. I have learned software security (well... it's an endless ongoing process), functional, procedural and object oriented programming, documenting, cloud computing, memory management schemes, monitoring, performance measuring, deployment automation, etc. etc. Learning Python is not the thing that will make you valuable 10 years from now when you are competing with both man and machine for a job. Knowing all about Azure will.
